# Subdomain not working with Devise Routes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I have the following routes

```
constraints :subdomain => "brands" do
    scope :module => "brands", :as => "brands" do

      devise_for :members

      # devise_for :users, controllers: {
      #   sessions: 'users/sessions'
      # }


    end
  end
```

When i go to `http://brands.lvh.me:3000/members/sign_up` i am getting the following error

> ActionController::RoutingError at /members/sign_up
>
> uninitialized constant Brands::RegistrationsController Application
>   Frames All Frames
>
> ```
> ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Dispatcher#controller
> actionpack (4.2.5.2) lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb, line 63
> ```

**Registration Controller** - `app/controllers/brands/members/registrations_controller.rb

```
class Brands::Members::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
# before_action :configure_sign_up_params, only: [:create]
# before_action :configure_account_update_params, only: [:update]

  # GET /resource/sign_up
  # def new
  #   super
  # end

  # POST /resource
  # def create
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/edit
  # def edit
  #   super
  # end

  # PUT /resource
  # def update
  #   super
  # end

  # DELETE /resource
  # def destroy
  #   super
  # end

  # GET /resource/cancel
  # Forces the session data which is usually expired after sign
  # in to be expired now. This is useful if the user wants to
  # cancel oauth signing in/up in the middle of the process,
  # removing all OAuth session data.
  # def cancel
  #   super
  # end

  # protected

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_sign_up_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # If you have extra params to permit, append them to the sanitizer.
  # def configure_account_update_params
  #   devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:account_update, keys: [:attribute])
  # end

  # The path used after sign up.
  # def after_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end

  # The path used after sign up for inactive accounts.
  # def after_inactive_sign_up_path_for(resource)
  #   super(resource)
  # end
end
```

Comment: I think if you will remove scope `scope :module => "brands", :as => "brands" do` it will work fine.

Comment: @MuhammadYawarAli but my controllers and views are namescoped

Comment: In a multitenant app of mine, with subdomains and a scope for locales, everything looks like you. The only difference I have is the devise controllers that I have override. Maybe you can do the same override but with an empty controller that inherit from devise controller. And in the routes just specify as `devise_for :members, controllers: {:sessions => "your_scope/sessions"}`

Comment: @codingaddicted do i need to do it for all the controllers?

Comment: First I would try just one controller to see if it resolves the error than I'll check the devise documentation to see which are my options (it's been a long time since I override those controller) ;)

Comment: @codingaddicted haha :) thanks man it worked :) will test for everything n get back here

Comment: Great! I'll post this as an answer. #Wokeupsmile

Comment: I add a thought about what could be the error source, maybe you can even fallback to the devise stuff if you don't need any custom views/controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer from the comments:

Create a controller to override the devise one. Add there anything specific your need or just inherit from the Devise controller.

Then in your routes you can tell devise to use the controller you just set with:

```
devise_for :members, controllers: {:sessions => "your_scope/sessions"}
```

[Devise doc (see section about configuring controllers and routes)](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise)

The "your_scope" section in the above code is related to the question which used a specific scope.

**thought**: Devise must be lost with the subdomain and scope thing an is not figuring which and where the controller are supposed to be. So maybe if I'm true, you can even skip the custom controller part and just tell Devise to use it's own and default controllers. In short, tell devise to forget about the scope and use the classic default mechanism.